# Nifi putsql processor error: Due to org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I try convert inject json file into postgresql for that first i try to convert my json file into sql format by using ConvertJSONToSQL processor, after that I pass flow into replacetext processor and after that I make flow into putsql processor. In putsql processor I got issue

> Due to org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of
>   range: 1

NIFI Flow:
[image]

PutSQL Error:
[image]

Replacement Value: 
`INSERT INTO public.detail (id,name, salary) VALUES (${id},${name},${salary})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the putSQL,you may have flowfile content like below.,

```
id-->1
name->stack
salary->12k

INSERT INTO public.detail (id,name, salary) VALUES (1,stack,12k)
```

if any value missing you would face issue that index of the value :1 is not found.

For example if 'id' attribute not exists in incoming flowfile you may receive that error.

**So you have to check all attributes in incoming flow file has exists and correctly formed insert query.
[Or]
Take that insert query formed after queuing in putSQL incoming queue and execute that in PostgresSQL.**

If it executes there then it execute putSQL also.